# Add a custom build target macro directory for multiple solution

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild, visual-studio-macros, post-build-event

I have an existing system with several solutions about 50 or more and all of them have a post build event that seem to paste the target built file in a special directory.

Post build event
copy $(TargetFileName) $(XXXSystemTarget)

The XXXSystemTarget points to a special directory where all of the DLLs process are staged for deployment.

Is there a way to make a custom Macro folder for the post built event. So far the articles that I found only points to project level customization. This would be difficult since I may need to change all the project file. Is there a system wide configuration file that I can change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try setting it as an environment variable. For example %systemroot% works.

http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3595.html